# Syntax error in "manage.py" file - django 2

Tags: django, manage.py

I do not understand what the problem is but I keep getting a syntax error for the **"from exc"** line even though I did not alter the code.  I have checked for un-closed parentheses and quotes and indentation look right to my beginner's eye.  The issue is that this is the out-of-the-box code for the Django 2.0 virtual environment so I can only assume Sublime somehow formatted it wrong when the file was dragged into the text editor?

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Django 2.0 is only compatible with Python 3, and this syntax is invalid in Python 2.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using Python 3 and I have Django 2.0 installed on my mac.  But I also have Django 1.11 installed.  Maybe my computer defaults to the wrong version?

Comment: @DanielRoseman for context, check out this link https://youtu.be/QVX-etwgvJ8?t=5m37s  (It's at the location where the "manage.py" file is being discussed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command line:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

The [tutorial](https://youtu.be/QVX-etwgvJ8?t=9m24s) I was following used just "python manage.py runserver" instead of "python3" and for some reason there was no error in the tutorial upon running but I received an error on my end.

Comment: Using a virtualenv is a good way to avoid this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If youre manage.py starts with "#!/usr/bin/env python", try changing it to "#!/usr/bin/env python3". This will force it to use Python 3.xx. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use "python3" if you have python 3X "python3 manage.py runserver" it work